Use a SQL Server to make a cursor to do a select command across multiple databases on multiple servers
I have a lot of databases on a bunch of servers that all have an identical schema.
I current have been just building a string into $command (using STUFF) that is
select * from [server1].[DBname1].dbo.[table] where [column] = @matchingtext
union 
select * from [server1].[DBname2].dbo.[table] where [column] = @matchingtext
union 
select * from [server1].[DBname3].dbo.[table] where [column] = @matchingtext
union 
select * from [server2].[DBname1].dbo.[table] where [column] = @matchingtext
union 
select * from [server2].[DBname2].dbo.[table] where [column] = @matchingtext
...etc.

and do an EXEC($command).
We have a database pools table that has the [server] and [DBname] as columns.
But if I try to do something more complicated I exceed the limits of the resources available.
How could I do this with a cursor?
I can get the above to work, but then I hit max limits and have to limit the servers I run per batch, and it is slow, but I think I don't have an option to improve that
I want a nested loop with the outer loop the server names and the inner loop the database names, although since both are in the same database pool table, I assume I could also just make it into one loop with a compound value?
here is a super abbreviated way I am doing it now, since it appears that I am not explaining myself competently
DECLARE @FOO NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @FOO = 
    STUFF((
        SELECT  'union select name from ['+p.server+'].['+p.DB+'].[dbo].contacts where email = test@test.com'
        FROM Pools p
        where 
         dbp.server in (
                        '01'
                        ,'02'
                        ,'03'
                        ,'04'
                        ,'05'
                        )
         and p.DB like '_m[_]%' 
         and p.DB not like '%test%' --eliminate test dbs
         and p.DB not like '%demo%' --eliminate demo dbs
         FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 5, '') --this removes 5 characters(union) from very first line in the stuff group
+' order by 1 desc'
exec(@FOO)


Could you be more specific about "exceeding the limits of the resources" ... what is the error exactly? And how many union statements are being union'ed exactly in in this query.

SSIS packages would work much better I believe than doing it this way.

for Topsail, I am exceeding the varriabe capacity ($command)

$command isn't a sql server syntax? what kind of system are you using? For strings, NVARCHAR(MAX) can contain 2 billions of chars which should be enough for your databases

When you start thinking you need cursors and nested loops you probably need to look at what you are trying to do. Looping is not something you want to do in sql server.

siggemannen, just a variable name, would you prefer $foo instead for my example?

Sean Lange
we have 5 servers with 1500+ total databases and yeah, I need to look at one (or more tables) for all the databases, so far I've been using a STUFF() but it is getting long and cumbersome and will eventually cause performance issues as my boss keeps wanting more and more reports like this
